# why top command in linux shows high us and low wa while cp many large files simultaneously?

Tags: cp, file-copy, io

I am copying 10 large files(which may costs 1 hour) simultaneously, and I used top command to check the cpu usage, but I found out 100.0 us and 0.0 wa. shouldn't it be IO-bound instead of CPU-bound? I suppose I should get high wa and low us, but it looks the opposite
[image]

Comment: How many times have you run the timings today? Your `top` shows 11 `cp` that have used 70 secs cpu each, one at 6mins and two at 20 mins (previous tests ?), and almost **all** of your 2GB used as cache. If you want accurate performance values, start over with no historic processes and a cleared cache.

Comment: thank you, i'll try it later